# Handle duplicate in R

Tags: r

I have four columns:

```
A           B   C   D(column d equal column b divided by column c) 
apple(01)   1   6   1/6
apple(78)   2   7   2/7
apple(3)    3   8   3/8
banana(12)  4   9   4/9
banana      5   10  5/10
```

Here is what I want to do. I want to ignore brackets first. Second, I want to sum the duplicate elements' B and C. Third, I want to come up new D.

```
A           B       C        D(column d equal column b divided by column c) 
apple       1+2+3   6+7+8    (1+2+3)/(6+7+8)
banana      4+5     9+10     (4+5)/(9+10)
```

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` to remove the brackets in 'A', use that as grouping variable, then with `summarise_each`, we get the `sum` of 'B' and 'C' and create the 'D' column by dividing 'B' by 'C'.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(A = sub("\\(.*", "", A)) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum), B:C) %>%
   mutate(D = B/C) 
#      A     B     C         D
#   <chr> <int> <int>     <dbl>
#1  apple     6    21 0.2857143
#2 banana     9    19 0.4736842
```

---

Or we can use `base R` methods with `aggregate`

```
 transform(aggregate(.~A, transform(df, A = sub("\\(.*", "", A))[-4], sum), D = B/C)
 #       A B  C         D
 #1  apple 6 21 0.2857143
 #2 banana 9 19 0.4736842
```